# Can I Use the Facebook Events API for a *Very* High-Traffic Website?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

This is a sort of general question for which I couldn't find a solid answer in the FB developer docs, but here it is (in 3 parts):

1. If I am working on a site that could get (very roughly) 300k-500k+ uniques with 500k to 1M+ page views per
   day, would it still be somehow possible to use the Facebook REST API to pull
   in Event data from a Facebook page without hitting the API rate limit?
2. If it is technically possible,
   do you know what would be the best practice with regards to rate
   limiting? (in a little more detail than what they have on the docs) :)
3. If it is NOT possible with FB's out-of-the-box
   capabilities, do you know of a solution to make this work (maybe
   creating a service or sort of job that copies the event data every
   15 mins to my own database, so that I take the hit instead of FB?)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @WizKid Not yet. I'm in the planning phase and was hoping to avoid a situation where the site goes live and fails. Basically, I'm just curious to know if anyone has experience using the Facebook Graph API to with high-traffic websites and whether or not they were able to make it work.

Comment: That you implement some form of caching on your end, instead of hitting the FB API on every page load, should be self-evident.

Comment: @CBroe Yep, this is pretty self-evident at this point. I know that there are solutions such as redis that can do this. While not being rocket-surgery by any stretch, that seems like that might require some more server-side skills than what I currently possess. Do you know of a solution, maybe something "out-of-the-box" that a front end developer such as myself could easily implement for this sort of caching?

Comment: Possible that there are ready-made solutions you can use, but you’d have to search for those yourself (firstly that is off-topic here, and secondly we don’t know what server-side techniques you have at your disposal.) If you want to implement it yourself, the most basic form would be that you store the data and the time it was last updated somewhere (database, files), and then when you read it back to output on the page, you check if it is older than timespan X - if no, you just output the data you read from storage, otherwise you need to make another API request to fetch the current data.

Comment: OK, cool. Some back end devs joined the project I was working on, and we decided on using Redis with Heroku. Thanks.